# Density of states for non-interacting Bosons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, density-of-states, quantum-statistics

I am tasked with calculating the density of states in terms of the angular frequency given the dispersion relation. But I couldn't help but think: why can't we calculate the density of states by determining the density operator in the occupation number representation and then project it into the $k$-space? or by using the expression of the density of states $\rho = \exp(-\beta E{n})/Z$, with $Z$ the partition function.

Comment: The density of states is fundermentally a property of the Hamiltonian rather than of a particular state. Now a thermal state for a given Hamiltonian does in principle contain enough information to reconstruct the Hamiltonian (by taking the matrix logarithm) and so the density of states, but this seems like a fairly indirect approach